# Fill online form (dropdown) with python

Tags: html, http, python-requests

how can I fill an online form with python (preferably with the requests library)?
On the website http://carsalesbase.com/european-car-sales-data/alfa-romeo/alfa-romeo-giulia/

there are four forms in total. Three are looking more or less identical.
I want to fill one of these three. It is a form with two dropdown menus.

```
<form action="http://carsalesbase.com/" class="search-form" method="get" role="search">

<input class="" id="hide-value" name="hide-value" type="hidden" value="1"/>

<select class="kelas1" id="brand-option" name="brand-option">
<option value="0">Select Brand</option>
<option value="82"> Group</option> <option value="17">Alfa Romeo</option> <option value="1">Alpina</option> <option value="249">Alpine</option> <option value="2">Aston Martin</option> <option value="67">Audi</option> <option value="68">Bentley</option> <option value="4">BMW</option> <option value="259">Borgward</option> <option value="8">Brilliance</option> <option value="69">Bugatti</option> <option value="27">Cadillac</option> <option value="75">Caterham</option> <option value="29">Chevrolet USA</option> <option value="28">Chevrolet-Daewoo</option> <option value="13">Chrysler</option> <option value="48">Citroën</option> <option value="54">Dacia</option> <option value="63">Daihatsu</option> <option value="14">Dodge</option> <option value="12">DR Motor</option> <option value="160">DS</option> <option value="18">Ferrari</option> <option value="19">Fiat</option> <option value="87">Fisker </option> <option value="24">Ford</option> <option value="33">Great Wall</option> <option value="34">Honda</option> <option value="30">Hummer</option> <option value="35">Hyundai</option> <option value="51">Infiniti</option> <option value="89">Isuzu</option> <option value="60">Jaguar</option> <option value="15">Jeep</option> <option value="36">Kia</option> <option value="3">Lada</option> <option value="70">Lamborghini</option> <option value="20">Lancia</option> <option value="23">Lancia-Chrysler</option> <option value="61">Land Rover</option> <option value="85">Landwind</option> <option value="64">Lexus</option> <option value="45">Lotus</option> <option value="83">Mahindra</option> <option value="21">Maserati</option> <option value="78">Maybach</option> <option value="40">Mazda</option> <option value="88">McLaren</option> <option value="9">Mercedes-Benz</option> <option value="41">MG</option> <option value="5">Mini</option> <option value="44">Mitsubishi</option> <option value="84">Morgan</option> <option value="52">Nissan</option> <option value="31">Opel/Vauxhall</option> <option value="47">Perodua</option> <option value="49">Peugeot</option> <option value="71">Porsche</option> <option value="46">Proton</option> <option value="91">Qoros</option> <option value="55">Renault</option> <option value="6">Rolls Royce</option> <option value="42">Rover</option> <option value="58">Saab</option> <option value="90">SAIC MG</option> <option value="72">Seat</option> <option value="73">Skoda</option> <option value="10">Smart</option> <option value="38">SSangYong</option> <option value="56">Subaru</option> <option value="57">Suzuki</option> <option value="62">Tata</option> <option value="86">Tesla</option> <option value="65">Toyota</option> <option value="74">Volkswagen</option> <option value="26">Volvo</option>
</select>
<select class="kelas1" id="model-option" name="model-option">
<option value="0">Select Model</option>
</select>
<input name="css-go" type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

I cannot find any good resource explaining how to do that :(

Who can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *click* on stuff with the requests library, but what you can do to get the data is mimic the HTTP request made after a form is submitted.

Use Chrome Network tools or Fiddler to analyze all of the requests your browser sends to the server when you submit a form. In [this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMYNj.png), when submitting a form with the car brand as Tesla and the car model as Model X, we can see the request's method, which is of type GET, the base URL, and the required parameters.
 We can use this information to simulate a webpage form submit and get the data that way:

```py
import requests

params = {
    "hide-value": 1,
    "brand-option": 86,
    "model-option": 2129,
    "css-go": "Go"
}
html = requests.get("http://carsalesbase.com/", params=params).text
print(html)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I also figured out about the GET and how it changes the URL. I use that to request the correct html, but I rather modify the url string itself instead of the params=params approach you posted. But I guess your approach would have some advantages. In the end I found the "model-option" in another JavaScript burried somewhere in the HTML which I could access with beautifulsoup, so I could avoid Selenium :) But next time I stumble across dynamic content I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I would use selenium, it lets you script what you would do as a user manually.

[Here's](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) a description of how to select elements on a webpage.

[This answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/2258) explains how to select an option from a dropdown.